# used raw_input and doesn't yield results

Tags: python, loading, raw-input

When using

```
first = raw_input('mol bio results + count')
f1 = open(first,'r')
f1data = f1.readlines()

second = raw_input('physics journal list')
f2 = open(second,'r')
f2data = f2.readlines()


total = 0
for line1 in f1data:
 i = 0
 for line2 in f2data:
    if line1 in line2:
        i+=1
        total+=1
 print line1 + str(i) + "\n"

print total
```

it only writes name of the first file ("mol bio results + count") on the screen and nothing else while it keeps loading forever.
Is my code wrong? Both files are seen in the place it shows the folder I'm working with.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you input something? When printing `mol bio results + count` the program expects some input from the user which will be stored in the variable `first` after hitting the Enter key. Same will be for variable `second`...

Comment: yeah i agree with @albert .This may be because the code expects input values for first and second.

Comment: Additionally, the input needs to be a valid file name since it will be passed to the `open()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

raw_input prints the string as a prompt and waits for input, and an enter.

I don't know how recent your python is but the syntax I've chosen will handle the file close for you (among other things)

I also took the liberty of reformatting and renaming a few variables for clarity

```
print("Please enter the file name for mol bio results + count")
first = raw_input('(Type it here and press enter) : ')

print("Please enter the file name for physics journal list")
second = raw_input(': ')

with open(first, 'r') as f1:
    f1data = f1.readlines()

with open(second, 'r') as f2:
    f2data = f2.readlines()

total = 0
for f1line in f1data:
    i = 0
    # print(len(f1line))
    for f2line in f2data:
        # print(len(f2line))
        if f1line.rstrip() in f2line:
            i += 1
            total += 1
    print f1line + ':' + str(i) + "\n"

print total
```

Comment: Fixed some bad pasting and added rstrip to allow the substrings to match.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code on my system. raw_input() works perfectly. Make sure that your code is in accordance to the python version you are using. Or maybe your python is broken.It could be that there's something stopping python from accessing your file. In that case check that you have the sufficient rights to read that file.